# Programatically add image into a content editor in Sharepoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, content-editor-web-part

How can I programtically display/add an image into a Content Editor in SharePoint Online?

I have managed to get an image programtically added to "Site Assets", but how can I as a second step get it added into a Content Editor?

Comment: You will need to provide more details of what you are trying to achieve.  I wonder why Content Editor webpart and not on the page directly

Answer (score 0):

> **Disclaimer**: *I see an influx of Asian accounts, asking questions as if they started with SharePoint yesterday, and think StackOverflow is a free training site.
>
>   It is not!
>
>   We are here to help you when you tried (very) hard to solve you coding problem yourself,
>
>   We are **not** here to do your job.*

---

Learn to use the PnP (Patterns & Practices) tool to create SharePoint content

https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP/wiki

But that's pushing content with Powershell from the back-end

If you want to create content Client-Side it is JSOM & REST you need to learn.

The question "Put a picture in a CEWP" **could** even imply you don't know the CEWP can not take binary content.

---

You need to learn & master those tools first,

I fear , you are now trying to build a house not knowing half the tools yet.

- Learn what the CEWP does
- (learn HTML,JavaScript)
- Learn JSOM
- Learn REST

Then build the house